# Caching Django OAuth access token

Tags: python, django, caching, oauth, django-rest-framework

I am using [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html) with Django Rest Framework

```
class DataView(BaseApiMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        _dict = {}  
        return self.successful_get_response({"results": _dict})
```

Everytime this time view is called, I see a db call to authenticate the token. Is there a way to Cache ONLY this db call ?

I am using Redis to Cache other queries, but not able to find a solution to cache the authentication call.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication token has to be validated *on every request*, so it's not possible to cache the query used for it. Every request checks that the token is

- **A real token** - Caching token queries can cause you to have periods of time where new tokens are not included (depending on which query is cached). The cache would have to be invalidated each time that a token is generated.
- **Not revoked** - If you revoked a token after the query was cached, you could run into issues where the token could still be used. The cache would have to be invalidated each time that a token is revoked.
- **Not expired** - OAuth tokens should naturally expire, you would have to keep invalidating the cache constantly (depending on the query).

And that's why the token is not cached anywhere, and instead *a single query* should be made to check the token on each request. This is equivalent to the checks that are made if you are using Django's sessions, to validate the session key and retrieve the session data on each request.

Comment: Is it to avoid giving a window of unsecure access ? But isn't it expensive ?

Comment: You have to weigh the drawbacks of cache invalidation with the drawbacks of making _a single query_. And I guess I didn't actually put it in my answer, but it's not possible out-of-the-box to cache the token.